# How to push changes after rename branch on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

The problem is that I started working on branch called `DDH-112` and I pushed it to the repository but then I changed name of this branch by using `git branch -m <newname>` because the previous one was wrong. Now I can't push changes to the new branch. It says:

```
    fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD:DDH-122

    To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push origin feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings
```

After doing `git push origin feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings` I get error:

`! [rejected]        feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings -> feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:apptension/dontdrivehigh.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

git pull doesn't help at all. I would like to have the Difference after pushing to the new-name branch. Is it possible to push these changes to this branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the command should be:

```
git push -u origin feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings
```

Second, the error message `feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings -> feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings (non-fast-forward)` makes sense only if you rename your branch with a name of a remote branch already existing, with existing commits.

`git pull` will help, provided [the associated remote branch is `feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309):

```
git fetch
git branch -u origin/feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings
git pull
# resolve conflicts
git push
```

Comment: When I enter `git branch -u feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings origin/feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings` it says that `fatal: branch 'origin/feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings' does not exist` ://

Comment: @Michal Sorry, try `git branch -u origin/feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings feature/DDH-129-implement-paddings`, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309